# equal height to columns bootstrap4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-4

I am using the bootstrap 4 and wanted to know how I leave all the columns of the same height ? If possible without using flexbox to be compatible with older browser ( bah !).

Thank you

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is what you do **if you want to use flexbox**

**The CSS**

```
.row.is-flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.row.is-flex > [class*='col-'] {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

/*
* And with max cross-browser enabled.
* Nobody should ever write this by hand. 
* Use a preprocesser with autoprefixing.
*/
.row.is-flex {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.row.is-flex > [class*='col-'] {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

**The html**

```
<div class="row is-flex">
    <div class="col-sm-4">...</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">...</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">...</div>
</div>
```

source (https://scotch.io/bar-talk/different-tricks-on-how-to-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height)

Comment: Bootstrap 4 now is flexbox by default so all this extra CSS is unnecessary. http://www.codeply.com/go/m20UAOFw79

Answer (score 1):

Use the first two solutions of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19695851) answer. The third solution involves a flexbox, but as you mentioned, you don't want that.

In case link doesn't work, here is **1st solution**:
*(Use with caution)*

```
.row {
    overflow:hidden;
}
[class*="col-"]{
    margin-bottom:-99999px;
    padding-botton:99999px;
}
```

**Solution 2**: *(Tables)*

```
.row {
   display:table;
}
[class*="col-"] {
    float:none;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: As mentioned in the other answer, these solutions don't really work as they break column wrapping and responsiveness. http://codeply.com/go/tPLjH5r6dJ

Comment: You should know right off the bat that if a solution is proposing you add `-99999px` to your styles, then it's obviously a total hack solution and should be used with extreme caution.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah the comment is for future visitors of this page from Google, but you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the *content* of the columns to be equal height? Bootstrap 4's [equal height cards](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/card/#groups) can be used for this. <strike>This uses `display:table` and `display:table-cell` when flexbox is not enabled</strike>.

**UPDATE**

Now that Bootstrap 4 (alpha 6) is flexbox by default, the columns are always equal height: http://www.codeply.com/go/m20UAOFw79

Comment: That wasn't the OP's question. He want's the Actual columns height. The equal height cards isn't a solution.

Comment: I was offering another option as the table-cell and negative margin methods have many adverse effects.